# Relaunch docker containers after system reboot

Tags: docker

I have few containers running on my Ubuntu-16.04 with docker-1.12 , i am running the container with few arguments as option.

But when i do system reboot again i need to launch all the containers, is there a way to auto launch container when system reboots.

Its in test phase now , so not using any platform which does this like Mesos etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [restart policy](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/start-containers-automatically/):

```
docker run --restart=always ...
```

or even add it to a running container:

```
docker update --restart=always <container>
```

Comment: Thanks .. i will try above solution

Answer (score 0):

Use `docker run --restart=<flag>`

for more [info](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/start-containers-automatically/#use-a-restart-policy)